# Firefox snap very slow after migrating from 22.04 to 23.04

Tags: firefox, snap, 23.04

Another Ubuntu release, another slow firefox snap complaint. I've uninstalled firefox, purged its settings under `~/snap/firefox`, removed any saved firefox snapshots, but it now takes up to 2 minutes for firefox to boot, cold or warm, makes no difference. Tried installing with `--classic` but the flag gets ignored since the snap is configured not to work unconfined.

I've monitored io with iotop and cpu/memory with htop when it's launching and can't see any obvious spikes (eg gzip or something else working hard to decompress the snap or writing/reading from disk).

I'm at my wits' end and thinking of forgoing snap completely since it has gotten horribly slow for some other snaps too (eg obs studio). Had no issues at all on 22.04, it's only after the upgrade to 23.04 that it has started to manifest.

Comment: you may find this useful - replacing FF snap with the deb package. https://fostips.com/ubuntu-21-10-two-firefox-remove-snap/

Comment: @graham thank you, I've ended up replacing FF with the debian one indeed, found this exact guide I think. I'm just annoyed I've had to do that as snap for me used to work fine, but something's happened in the update that's completely messed it up. It feels suspiciously like snap is waiting for some kind of response with a timeout of about 2 minutes, gives up and only then launches the app